# Not able to play a mp3 in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

Document directory url

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/895DE1A3-5D2E-462B-8D13-518B7CAFC6C7/Documents/146791.mp3
```

Code I am using to play this url

```
do {
       print(url)

       audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
       guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }

       player.prepareToPlay()
       player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

error I am getting

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

Comment: You're probably saving the url over time. Don't. Derive it freshly each time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)

            player.volume = 0.6
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()

        }
        catch {
            print("File not found")
        }
```

Comment: this is the file url.

Comment: file:///Users/aggu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11DD7BE6-213D-4C0B-AA2E-ED8B0A64AFEC/data/Containers/Data/Application/C3098498-160E-491B-8EBA-E6239132DF53/Documents/661191.mp3